# v-for variable not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Just trying to go through an array of objects that has come up from the backend and displaying those objects on the frontend. Vue is complaining that "event" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. I'm guessing it doesn't like my event variable in my `v-for` in the template.

Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span v:for="(event, index) in eventList" :key="event.id">
            {{ event.id }}
        </span>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
import eventHelpers from "@/mixins/eventHelpers";
export default {
    name: 'eventsList',
    mixins: [eventHelpers],
    data() {
        return {
            eventList: [],
        }
    },
    async mounted() {
        this.eventList = await this.getAllEvents();
    },
    methods: {

    }
}
</script>
```

This `<span>` is going to be a card component eventually, once I get this data working.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `v:for` is not a valid synonym for `v-for`.

Comment: @ruakh hah! You're right. That was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think these are your problems but you have got some typos in there.
1) It's v-for, not v:for
2) Inside your Vue instance, I'm pretty sure it should be data:{}, not data(){}